# How to access JSON field in angular?

Tags: json, angular, variables

I have this type of json:`[{"__data__":{"name":"student","group":1,"number":30,"foreignLanguage":true,"mark":10,"friend":"Alex"}}]`
How can I access friend's name in Angular instantly and put it into a variable?

Comment: Where is your JSON ? What's your file structure ? Do you get it from an Http request ? What did you tried already ?

Comment: `response[0]['__data__']['friend']`? Why is it an array and why is it enclosed in `__data__` property if the object needs to be directly accessed? If you get it from back-end, try to return only the object that is required. Then you could do `response['friend']`.

Comment: @MichaelD it is get from the backend, but I don't know how to make modifications to the code to return only the required object

Comment: @Viktor Please provide some code or context so we can help you with modifications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

As stated here: https://angular.io/guide/http

You can do:

```
this.http.get(studentUrl) .subscribe((result) => {
  this.student = result["__data__"];
});
```